# How to round to nearest 0, 5 or 9 integer

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

How to round a given number to a 0, 5 or 9, which ever is closest?
I've tried with:

```
=MROUND(I2,5)-((MOD(MROUND(I2,5),10))=0)
```

But I need zeros too, this only gives me fives and nines.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=1*(ROUNDDOWN(A2/10,0)&INDEX({0,5,9},MATCH(MIN(ABS({0,5,9}-MOD(A2,10))),ABS({0,5,9}-MOD(A2,10)),0)))
```

- MOD to get right digit of cell
- Find the distance between {0,5,9} and the right digit and MATCH it to the closest digit
- Concatenate right of the matched digit to the left digit and multiply by 1

---

Added a 0 to `ROUNDDOWN` to satisfy [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), producing the following:
[image: here]
[image: plot]

Comment: You might need to change {0,5,9} to {0,5,9,10} so that (say) 9.6 rounds to 10.

Comment: Fair point - anyway OP is satisfied so I should keep out of it!

Comment: I feel like 7.00 should round to 9 rather than 5? Did OP clarify?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand of your obscure request, you need to take last whole digit and any fraction (so with  `123.456` we'll be looking at `3.456`) and compare it to this chart:

### Interpretation:

***`If it is:         Then it becomes:`***      
`>= 0   And <2.5          0`                  
`>= 2.5 And < 7           5`                  
`>= 7   And < 9.5         9`                  
`>= 9.5 and < 10         10 (zero rounded up)`

### Code:

```
Function round059(num As Double)
    Dim L As Single, R As Single
    L = Int(num / 10) * 10
    R = num - L
    If R >= 2.5 And R < 7 Then
        R = 5
    Else
        If R >= 7 And R < 9.5 Then
            R = 9
        Else
            If R >= 9.5 Then
                R = 10
            Else
                R = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If
    round059 = L + R
End Function
```

### Test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Double
    For x = -0.1 To 10.1 Step 0.2
        Debug.Print "    " & x & ":", , round059(x)
    Next x
End Sub
```

### Result:

```
-0.1:                   0    
0.1:                    0    
0.3:                    0    
0.5:                    0    
0.7:                    0    
0.9:                    0    
1.1:                    0    
1.3:                    0    
1.5:                    0    
1.7:                    0    
1.9:                    0    
2.1:                    0    
2.3:                    0    
2.5:                    5    
2.7:                    5    
2.9:                    5    
3.1:                    5    
3.3:                    5    
3.5:                    5    
3.7:                    5    
3.9:                    5    
4.1:                    5    
4.3:                    5    
4.5:                    5    
4.7:                    5    
4.9:                    5    
5.1:                    5    
5.3:                    5    
5.5:                    5    
5.7:                    5    
5.9:                    5    
6.1:                    5    
6.3:                    5    
6.5:                    5    
6.7:                    5    
6.9:                    5    
7.1:                    9    
7.3:                    9    
7.5:                    9    
7.7:                    9    
7.9:                    9    
8.10000000000001:       9    
8.3:                    9    
8.5:                    9    
8.7:                    9    
8.9:                    9    
9.1:                    9    
9.3:                    9    
9.5:                    10    
9.7:                    10    
9.9:                    10    
10.1:                   10
```

### Ya?

Comment: For me this is better because it gives the results I would expect between 9.5 and 10

Comment: No, I'm not the original poster but I wanted to upvote & comment.

Comment: Gotcha - I didn't even look at your name :-)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody commented on the `8.10000000000001` in the example result...  I left it there kinda hoping someone *would* mention a fix, because (although not a big deal in this case) I've dealt with it before but can't remember what causes it or how to prevent it.  Something to do with handling the data type differently.